# Jsoup gives the same document from two different urls

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am making a java aplication for kakuro and I wanted to scrape the boards from a site. Now the dimensions "3x3",  and "4x4" don't work but in the meantime "5x5", "9x8" and "13x13" work as intended.
Am i missing somthing from the library or is it because of the site I am scraping from?
Oh and it just scrapes it all the same every time even tho it is supposed to regenerate a new board.

Here I set find what board I want to use and send it to constructor.

```
switch (selection) {
            case "3x3" -> scraper = new Scraper("https://www.kakuros.com/?s=3x3", 3, 3);
            case "4x4" -> scraper = new Scraper("https://www.kakuros.com/", 4, 4);
            case "5x5" -> scraper = new Scraper("https://www.kakuros.com/?s=5x5", 5, 5);
            case "9x8" -> scraper = new Scraper("https://www.kakuros.com/?s=9x8", 9, 8);
            default -> scraper = new Scraper("https://www.kakuros.com/?s=13x13", 13, 13);
        }
```

The constructor ccatches the right url and creates it as a String.

```
public Scraper(String url, int row, int col){
        this.url = url;
        this.rowSize = row;
        this.columnSize = col;
        createTable();
    }
```

But the next line just sumbles and doesn't work properly
`Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();`

I was trying to scrape two different sites and wasn't able to get them to be different.

Comment: Are you sure that the board isn't rendered by javascript? JSoup doesnt execute JS

Comment: It is in the script part of the hmtl so I suppose so but it is really weird that on some links it works without a mistake but 2 out of 5 are bot working.

Comment: Can you show how you handle the received Document?

Comment: String script = document.select("script").get(1).toString();
String[] pars = script.split("\\n");
But the problem is not how I parse because the Document I get with the Jsoup.connect is always the same.